# Vertical dropout chips for Civia Bryant

Tags: dropouts, derailleur-hanger

I have a Civia Bryant that has horizontal dropouts and an Alfine rear hub. The Bryant had interchangeable vertical/horizontal dropouts I didn’t get the vertical dropouts from the shop when I bought the bike and now regretting it. 
Might anyone know where I could find vertical dropouts for the Bryant? I contacted Civia and they did not have any in stock. They suggested a derailleur hanger/tensioner option but it would be really nice to find the original proper dropouts.

Chris

Comment: Any chance these would fit? https://www.cycle-frames.com/bicycle-frame-tubing/MODULAR-ROAD-DROPOUT-IN-STEEL-FOR-TRACK.html

Comment: What's your purpose in replacing the horizontal dropouts with vertical ones?  Maybe there's another solution.

Comment: Andrew - I’m using an Alfine rear hub and I want to convert to a QR hub and conventional derailleur for easier flat repair and less weight. I know that problem Solvers and Origin 8 make a tensioner/ derailleur hanger but it would be nice to work with original parts.

Comment: I realise your post was made quite some time ago but I was wondering if you ever worked out some sort of solution? I've been contemplating the same thing for the last 3-4 years and still want to keep my Bryant, but would also like to switch to dropouts with a derailleur hanger (not the Problemsolver chain tensioner hanger path preferably). Interested to hear what you ended up doing.

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet is to do what research you can to find shops that were stocking that bike who might have then bought spares of the dropout kits, and then see if you can get one to sell you some remotely and send them in the mail. There's a good chance there's some shop out there that still has them, because they were the way you replaced the hanger on that bike.

Comment: The bike is a qbp product so I’m wondering if there may be a related model’s parts that might be available and close enough

Answer (score 2):

Here's a photo of a Bryant frame from

[image: From https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVYvg88rz-w]

---

Keep contacting Civia - could be that sufficient demand will encourage them to make more.

https://civiacycles.com/bikes/archive/bryant

---

Another option is to consider is getting some made.  You have the existing "chips" which can provide a template for the bike interface side.  The horizontal track end is a simple shape, being two parallel hardened surfaces at a specified distance apart.

Sure its going to cost money, but should be within reach of an engineering firm.   You may have to leave the bike frame with them for trial fitting.  May also pay to buy some generic weld-in trackends to act as a guide.

Comment: Thanks Criggie Yeah that’s the next step, trying to contact dealers that carried the Bryant. I know somebody has the vertical dropouts laying around and would love to just get rid of them. I appreciate your feedback!